Rails log files in Docker volume are not being updated inside Docker container
I am trying to set up promtail as part of my docker-compose setup to collect my Rails logs.
The Rails app is running outside Docker, directly in the host machine through:
rails s

This is the promtail part of my docker-compose.yml:
  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:3.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./docker/promtail/config.yml:/etc/promtail/config.yml
      - ./log:/var/log/rails
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml

When I start the container:
docker-compose up promtail

I see the files on the container: /var/log/rails are updated:
docker-compose exec promtail tail /var/log/rails/development.log

Then I make some requests to my app, and new logs are added in my local files (host, outside the Docker):
tail ./logs/development.log

But the new logs are replicated in the same file in the Docker container:
docker-compose exec promtail tail /var/log/rails/development.log

I can continue generating logs through my Rails app, but the logs are not replicated in the log file into the container.
The interesting part is that if I execute this in the host (outside the Docker):
echo "XXX" >> ./log/development.log

Suddenly, all the logs are replicated in the Docker container.
Another way to force the replication is to kill the Rails app. Then, all the logs are replicated in the Docker container.
I would say some buffer Rails logger causes it has, but then I should not see the logs in the host machine being updated through tail -f .log/development.log
How can I ensure the log files are replicated inside the Docker container when updated outside?
Update: If my Rails app also runs in a Docker container, the log files will be synchronized properly in the promtail container.
